# How to implement interactive graph from plotly in overleaf?

Tags: graph, jupyter-notebook, latex, plotly, interactive

I want to implement interactive graph from plotly in overleaf. However, overleaf removed the communication with plotly in the V2 version. Is it still possible somehow to implement interactive graph in overleaf and therefore in pdf? 
I want to hide/unhide line, zoom in and see value of different points when clicking on it.

I saw this question a couple times before, but the answere was only to zoom in or use javascript and implementing different picture on top of eachother.

However, this is not what i am looking for. I am looking for a really interactive in PDF. Does somebody know how this is possible?

Comment: Can anyone help with this question? I have exactly the same problem :(